# Blazor-Server .NET 8 custom authentication is broken if page is reloaded

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have a custom authentication which works as expected:

A login is required for the entire application in order to access all pages. This also works as expected. However, you have to log in again when the website is refreshed (F5), although the session with the corresponding values is still available.

_Imports.razor (To ensure that a login is always required):

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
...
@attribute [Authorize]
```

Program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<ProtectedBrowserStorage, ProtectedSessionStorage>();
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/login";
            });
```

Routes.razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)">
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1"/>
    </Found>
</Router>
```

CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.cs:

```
  public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
  {
      private static readonly ClaimsPrincipal         anonymousUser = new(new ClaimsIdentity());
      private readonly        ProtectedBrowserStorage browserStorage;

      public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ProtectedBrowserStorage browserStorage)
      {
          this.browserStorage = browserStorage;
      }

      public async Task AuthenticateUser(AuthModel user)
      {
          var authUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(CreateIdentity(user));
          await browserStorage.SetAsync(Konstanten.BrowserStorageKey, user).ConfigureAwait(false);
          NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateForAsync(authUser));
      }

      public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
      {
          try
          {
              var result   = await browserStorage.GetAsync<AuthModel>(Konstanten.BrowserStorageKey).ConfigureAwait(false);
              var identity = result.Success ? CreateIdentity(result.Value) : anonymousUser;
              return await GetAuthenticationStateForAsync(identity);
          }
          catch
          {
              return await GetAuthenticationStateForAsync(anonymousUser);
          }
      }


      private Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateForAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user) => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));

      private ClaimsPrincipal CreateIdentity(AuthModel user)
      {
          var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
          {
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString())
          }, "apiauth_type");
    
          return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
      }
```

Login.razor:

```
private async Task OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
{
    await ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)Provider).AuthenticateUser(new AuthModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Username = model.Username });
}
```

Comment: Have you made any progress? You have my upvote as I am facing the same issue as you. Been having a really hard time finding resources on properly implementing custom authentication in .NET 8.

Comment: Are you using prerendering (with Blazor WebApp)? If so, problem could be that to identify auth state, the website must be rendered to get the session storage. So it will be rendered first with the anonymous user.